# Azure Pipeline Argument Formatting YAML

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, kubernetes-helm

I am working on some yaml for a pipeline and im using th Helm Task.I need to pass in arguments but I can only pass them in as a single line

```
arguments: --set key=$(value) --set key=$(value) --set key=$(value) --set key=$(value) --set key=$(value) --set key=$(value)--set key=$(value) --set key=$(value)
```

Can't seem to find a good way to add a hard return in yaml. It would be nice if it looked like this

```
arguments:
--set key=$(value)
--set key=$(value)
--set key=$(value)
--set key=$(value)
--set key=$(value)
```

Comment: How's your issue going?

Comment: Look at answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. https://yaml-multiline.info/. You need to use a Block Style Indicator.

Example:

```
arguments: >
  --set key=$(value)
  --set key=$(value)
  --set key=$(value)
  --set key=$(value)
  --set key=$(value)
```

The ">" lets the compiler know that this is a block and converts it to a single string

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, question is more related to azure pipelines rather than helm. Did you try the following?

```
arguments:
- "--set key=$(value)"
- "--set key=$(value)"
- "--set key=$(value)"
- "--set key=$(value)"
- "--set key=$(value)"
```

Comment: Getting back to this story soon ill leave an update if this worked